# spring quartz doesn't work

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I've got some controller, which performs some task and Tomcat. It works fine.
I want some job that will work every 5 seconds during its work.

I've created xml file `quartz-config.xml` with data

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="someTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="someJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="someTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="someJob"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean id="someJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
     <property name="name" value="someJob" />
     <property name="jobClass" value="com.service.scheduler.SomeJob" />
</bean>
```

and added path to xml file in my `spring-context.xml`.
I have created class

```
public class SomeJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    public void execute(JobDataMap jobDataMap) throws JobExecutionException {
        executeInternal(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
       System.out.println("SCHEDULER WORKS!");
    }

}
```

But it doesn't do anything in console. I am only getting messages `batch acquisition of 0 triggers`. 
Why? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check quart web page.

**org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount**
The maximum number of triggers that a scheduler node is allowed to acquire (for firing) at once. Default value is 1. The larger the number, the more efficient firing is (in situations where there are very many triggers needing to be fired all at once) - but at the cost of possible imbalanced load between cluster nodes.
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigMain][1]

Comment: I didn't configure this parameter and I have only one trigger.